# Dynamically adjust setMinDate()

Tags: android, datepicker

I have two date pickers A,B(assume). 'A' must not allow any dates before today and 'B' must not allow any dates before 'A'. 
My present code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (id == 999) {
        DatePickerDialog datePicker= new DatePickerDialog(this,
                myDateListener, year, month, day);
        datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()- 1000);
        return  datePicker;
    } else if (id == 998) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                myDateListener, year1, month1, day1);
        datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate( cal.getTimeInMillis() );
        return datePicker;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The above code just doesn't allow both A&B to show any dates before today.
Could you help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Pass Date as milliseconds (a long var) and the in your create dialog just convert it back to date and set min date for date picker.